# Can´t get the url of a new window page opened by a click on a button

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Can´t get the url of a new window page opened by a click on a button.

```
it('Start test', () => { 
  element.all(by.buttonText('Launch Test')).click().then ( function() {
  browser.sleep(2000);
  browser.switchTo().window('Test');
  console.log('url ' + browser.getCurrentUrl());    
  expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).
  toBe('https://localhost:44323/#/test/run/test_id');

 }); 
 });
```

This code always returns the url of the current page not of new window page.

```
Failed: no such window
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong suggestion about the root of problem. Error appears before the system even can take an url. System can not switch to the 'Test' window. Can you try to implement switching in more common way:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){
        //do your stuff on the pop up window
    });
});
```

Comment: failed due:

TestiD 77 Test Result 5
    × TestRail ID 77: Start test
      - Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

Comment: this is complitly different issue, and it is not the scope of current